# How to subset my main data set based on random samples using R?

Tags: r, dataset

I am new to R and I am using Rstudio to do my data analysis. I have a main data set called 'mydata1' (extract shown below):

```
ID    Market    Expenditure
100   UK         51,000
101   UK         12,500
...   ...        ...
1500  Germany    9,200
```

'mydata1' has around 11,000 observations (rows) with different markets in the 'Market' column.

I want to use R to create a subset of that data set by taking an appropriate sample size for each market. In some way, it will be a sample stratified by Market.

How do I go about creating this subset (say, mydata2) using R?

Note: It would be great if R could give me a sample for each market that is representative of the population size for that market (based, say on a 95% CI).

Comment: Here's one option: `library(dplyr); mydataSubset = mydata %>% group_by(Market) %>% sample_n(100)` will give you 100 randomly selected rows from each market.

Comment: Thanks, but I need to specify the sample size (in your example, 100). I want R to give me a sample for each market that is representative of the population size for that market (based, say on a 95% CI).

Comment: Do you mean you want to sample a percentage of the rows from each market, or that you want to specify a different number of rows to sample from each market? I'm not sure how the 95% CI comes into it. If you want the smallest confidence interval, use all the data, rather than a subset. In addition, assuming the size of the population is much larger than the number of observations, the appropriate sample size (for a given variance) to limit the confidence interval to a given size is independent of the total population size.

Comment: It might be easier to help you if you provide more information on what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Because you do not provide data,  I can't provide actual code,  but you can make stratified samples like you want using the `strata` function from the [sampling](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sampling/sampling.pdf)  package.

Comment: @eipi10 Let's say I want my new data set to be made up of samples from each market. To note that the number of observations per market varies. Let us forget the 95% CI I mentioned. May be samples equivalent to, say, 40% from each market. Does this make sense?

Comment: If you want 40% of the observations from each market, instead of `sample_n(100)` from my first comment, use `sample_frac(0.4)`.

Comment: Thanks. I will give this a shot and see how it goes!